# максимум из количества в каждой группе

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть 2 таблицы:

`customer(c_id number,c_st vchar)`- ид покупателя и штат;

```
|c_id|c_st|
|0001|NY  |
|0002|NY  |
|0003|TX  |
|0004|NY  |
|0005|NY  |
|0006|TX  |
|0007|TX  |
|0008|MA  |
```

`order(o_id number,c_id number)` - ид заказа и ид покупателя.

```
|o_id|c_id|
|0001|0001|
|0002|0007|
|0003|0001|
|0004|0001|
|0005|0008|
|0006|0003|
|0007|0003|
```

Задача "вывести заказчиков, с самым большим количеством заказов в каждом штате".
Количество для каждого заказчика нашел:

```
select sales_order.customer_id as sid, state as st, 
       count(sales_order.order_id) as cnt
from sales_order, customer
group by sales_order.customer_id, state 
order by st asc, cnt desc;
```

но не пойму как дальше к этому подзапросу обратиться, чтобы в каждом штате получить покупателя с максимальным числом заказов
примерно так

```
|c_st|c_id|cnt|
|MA  |0008|  1|
|NY  |0001|  3|
|TX  |0003|  2|
```

Comment: добавьте, пожалуйста, пример заполнения и ожидаемый результат

Answer (score 1):

Для получения строго одного покупателя, с максимальным количеством (даже если с одинаковым максимальным количеством есть несколько покупателей) можно посчитать строки в нужном порядке и отобрать первые из них:

```
select * from (
    select sales_order.customer_id as sid, state as st, 
           count(sales_order.order_id) as cnt,
           row_number() over(partition by state order by count(1) desc) RN
      from sales_order, customer
     group by sales_order.customer_id, state 
   ) X
  where RN=1
  order by st asc, cnt desc;
```

Для поиска всех покупателей с одинаковым максимальным количеством в вышеприведенном запросе надо заменить функцию `row_number()` на функцию `rank()`

Answer (score 0):

Не проверял.

```
with t as
(select sales_order.customer_id as sid, state as st, 
       count(sales_order.order_id) as cnt
from sales_order, customer
group by sales_order.customer_id, state)
select t.st,t.sid,t.cnt from t join
(select st, max(cnt) cnt from t group by st) x
on t.st= x.st and t.cnt=x.cnt;
```

Comment: спасибо, то что надо

Comment: @Flatterer Избегайте  комментариев типа "Спасибо". Спасибо это кнопки "галочка" и/или "стрелочка наверх" см. чуть выше слева.