# Выбрать строку с максимальной датой

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть табличка. Сервера приложений могут быть двух типов. Каждого типа сервер приложений может быть разного количества в определенную дату.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если выбираем дату за определенный период, как сделать чтобы выбрались строки с максимальной датой на этот период и соответственно, с количеством, которое соответствует этой максимальной дате? То есть, если мы выбираем период

```
  startdate<='2018-06-04'
  and enddate >= '2018-06-02'
```

то должны получить строки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я не очень силен в sql. можно хотя бы примерно как должно это выглядеть?

Comment: >> которое соответствует этой максимальной дате
Какая это дата: startdate или enddate?

Comment: прошу прощения, то есть какое количество определенного типа на конец периода.

Comment: то есть у нас получается что 06-04 уже был сервер типа 1 количеством 1. Значит надо брать его. сервер типа 1 количеством 2 закончил свое существование 06-03

Comment: Укажите (тегом) точно DBMS и (в теге, если существует, или в тексте вопроса) версию сервера. Для разных серверов и даже для разных их версий решение будет различным.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/755872/194569

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для MS SQL Server

> ```
> create table "tbl"
> ( 
>   "type" varchar(10),
>   "count" numeric,
>   "sidp" varchar(10),
>   "enddate" date,
>   "startdate" date
> );
> GO
> ```

> ```
> insert into "tbl" ("type","count","sidp","enddate","startdate") values
> (1,2,'','2018-06-03','2018-06-02'),
> (1,1,'','2018-06-18','2018-06-04'),
> (0,1,'','2018-06-03','2018-06-01');
> GO
> ```

> ```
> select
>   T02.*
> from 
> (
> select
>   "type",
>   max("enddate") "enddate"
> from "tbl"
> where
>   startdate<='2018-06-04'
>   and enddate >= '2018-06-02'
> group by 
>   "type"
> ) T01
> join "tbl" T02 on 
>   T01."type" = T02."type" 
>   and T01."enddate" = T02."enddate"
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> type | count | sidp | enddate             | startdate          
> :--- | :---- | :--- | :------------------ | :------------------
> 0    | 1     |      | 03/06/2018 00:00:00 | 01/06/2018 00:00:00
> 1    | 1     |      | 18/06/2018 00:00:00 | 04/06/2018 00:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=aca6c293f4292237460bb9bc4770ad35)*

т.к. появился значок [image: Postgesql] можно использовать оконные функции

как тут 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а возможность задать период для поиска?

Comment: тут получается просто максимальная дата. А мне нужна максимальная для периода. То есть она не всегда будет максимальной в таблице.

Comment: Выборку по периоду ранее пропустил, но
сейчас добавил

Comment: тип text замен на varchar(10) т.к. в реализации сервера не выполняется сравнение по text

Comment: В MS SQL, postgresql и многих других БД можно несколько проще https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=d4925f99220b04f1ce25d98e7b5dcd31

Comment: спасибо, получилось способом Mike.

Comment: а можно ли еще дополнительно спросить: как сделать какой нибудь признак того, попадали ли несколько записей о сервере данного типа в необходимый промежуток времени? то есть менялось ли количество серверов в данный промежуток.

Comment: В оконных функциях
https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/functions-window
 есть функции lag и lead, которые позволяют сравнить текущее значение "cout" со значением в предыдущей/следующей записи