# как получить только одну строку с минимальным значением по одному полю

Tags: sql, sql-server

есть результат промежуточной выборки, список строк всех прайс-листов, нужно получить все товары с минимальной ценой

```
declare @price_tmp table (
[price_id] int,
[tov_id] int,
[cena] float)
```

в примере строки с ценами по одному товару

```
insert into @price_tmp(price_id, tov_id, cena) values
(545775542, 500, 723.31),
(544532913, 500, 728.49),
(545119100, 500, 613.99),
(545135079, 500, 671.85),
(545686947, 500, 719.93),
(546147540, 500, 761.32),
(545138929, 500, 718.63),
(545143010, 500, 717.89),
(545147309, 500, 720.61),
(545153624, 500, 720.61),
(545157008, 500, 718.74);
```

в данном примере в итоге должна быть всего одна строка
    545119100, 500, 613.99

пишу:

```
select min(cena), tov_id, price_id from @price_tmp group by tov_id, price_id
```

в итоге получаю весь набор

как получить только одну строку с минимальным значением по полю cena и сгруппировав по полю tov_id,  при этом price_id тоже нужен в результирующей выборке

Comment: `select top 1 min(cena), tov_id, price_id from @price_tmp group by tov_id, price_id`?

Comment: @Anamnian, не пойдет, попробуй выполнить свой код

Comment: в данном примере список цен по одному товару, в рабочем состоянии в этом наборе примерно 20тыс товаров и примерно 2млн строк

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вариант 1** [Использование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/858005/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9/858013#858013)  по алгоритму Mike (предпочтительней)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
select  *
  from (
    select price_tmp.*,  row_number() over(partition by  [tov_id] order by [cena] asc) RN
      from price_tmp
  ) T01
 where RN=1
```

**Вариант 2** первым нашли минимальную цену для товара и вторым, в таблице нашли запись со всеми колонками сравнив цену и товар

Если в таблице будет несколько товаров, то для каждого товара будет найдена одна запись

```
select 
  P01.*
from price_tmp P01
  join
  (
  select 
    tov_id,
    min(cena) as cena
  from price_tmp
  group by
    tov_id
  ) P02 
  on 
    P01.tov_id = P02.tov_id
    and P01.cena = P02.cena
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES m.cena, m.tov_id, m.price_id
FROM (
    select 
        min(cena) as cena, 
        tov_id, 
        price_id 
    from @price_tmp group by tov_id, price_id
) m
ORDER BY cena
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from (
  select tov_id, min(cena)
  from price_tmp 
  group by tov_id)
```